# table view not getting refreshed on opening app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

When the app is open or in background, I am using notification in `appdelegate` to update the message box table and then it is working.

Appdelegate (in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification`):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("changeMessageBox", object: nil)
```

---

`MessageViewController`:

in `viewdidload`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector  (MessagesViewController.reloadtable), name: "changeMessageBox", object: nil)
```

---

```
func reloadtable() 
{
    clearArrays()
    if (PFUser.currentUser()!["firebaseUID"] !== nil)
    {

        self.updateResultArray(PFUser.currentUser()!["firebaseUID"] as! String)

        resultsTable.reloadData()

    }
}
```

---

and data is refreshed in the message box.

But when the app is closed and i recieve a chat, the message box ( the window with messages from all the people not the individual chat) does not get updated.

I have to open the app, go to message box ,then back to main page and go back to message box again only then the table view gets refreshed.

Do you guys know what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for post notification,

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { () -> Void in

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("changeMessageBox", object: nil)

})
```

I was having same issue and resolved like this. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Receiving Notification while app in closed or in suspended state will trigger

```
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
```

Try to post notification in this method. i guess it will update your view.

Additionally Refer this document if you have query with Notifiacation

http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/